# how to get id from list view and send to other activity

Tags: android, listview

i want when click on User info list view item (fill with adapter) , get user_id, 
i use this code in main activity :

```
    // long click on listview items
        LIST_USER.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("Clicked item id", " "+ id);
//                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), UpdateActivity.class);
//                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_ID", id);
//                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

yet no problem !
but when send user_id to update activity database has stopped !!
use this code in update activity :

public class UpdateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DatabaseHelper DB_HELPER;

```
private TextView TXT_VIEW;
private EditText EDT_NAME;
private EditText EDT_AGE;
private EditText EDT_GENDER;
private EditText EDT_PASS;
private EditText EDT_DESC;
private EditText EDT_PIC;
private Button BTN_UPDATE;
private Button BTN_DELETE;
private String STR_ID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);

    TXT_VIEW = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.textView);
    EDT_NAME = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EDT_AGE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EDT_GENDER = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    EDT_PASS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    EDT_DESC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    EDT_PIC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    BTN_UPDATE = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button) ;
    BTN_DELETE = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    DB_HELPER = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    STR_ID = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_ID");
    TXT_VIEW.setText(STR_ID);
```

display user_id in log info :

[image]
[image]

thank's

Comment: Share the console log (error)

Comment: W/Bundle: Key EXTRA_ID expected String but value was a java.lang.Long.  The default value <null> was returned.
W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
          java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The starting problem is in the types, you are passing a long and reading it as a string, the cast exception is raised in the onCreate and resulting in the crash. This should make it work:

```
private long STR_ID;
//...
STR_ID = getIntent().getLongExtra("EXTRA_ID");
TXT_VIEW.setText(String.valueOf(STR_ID));
```